# How to find out why debug shows many exceptions in service fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am running a application I made in service fabric on the local dev cluster.

when debugging and seeing the output, its filled with

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
```

everything is green and I havent found anything that dont work as expected. So what exactly do I do to find out what it is that is an InvalidOperation :) ?

Checked event logs and diagnostic events and no errors are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably catched and handled inside SFA, if it would be serious it would be rethrown so I would not worry about it too much.

Might have to do with the fact that it is the local dev environment and certain operations are not valid in a non-azure / on-premises installation environment.

A local dev environment for example lets you simulate a 5 node cluster on a single machine. Any exceptions caused by that might be catched and if it is detected that it is a non-real world environment it could be handled in a different way.

Comment: I've also seen it happen in production

Comment: See https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/435#issuecomment-331520953 - This is a first chance exception that is thrown and caught inside our transaction class in the happy path when transactions are disposed.
It was introduced in the latest version of the runtime unintentionally and we have logged a bug for it. We will fix it in the upcoming release and you should stop seeing these in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing exactly the same thing, but in production as well and agree that I don't think it's a problem, though it will impact performance.

I'll put a few more things in context to hopefully help other people who see the same thing.

Here's my code which works correctly and I don't see the exception being thrown all the way up.

```
Log.Information("About to record activity for {Machine}", machineId);
using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
{
    await map.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, machineId, _ => new SystemInfo { LastSeenUtc = timestampUtc }, (_, info) =>
    {
        info.LastSeenUtc = timestampUtc;
        return info;
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await tx.CommitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Log.Information("Just committed transaction {Tx}", tx.TransactionId);
}
Log.Information("Recorded activity for {Machine}", machineId);
```

And with the debug output window. I'm using `serilog` with the `Serilog.Sinks.Debug` sink to capture the output.

```
[07:48:27 INF] About to record activity for d6441d45e1834db7860c00a8074652f9
[07:48:27 INF] Just committed transaction 131489813076754311
[07:48:27 INF] Recorded activity for d6441d45e1834db7860c00a8074652f9
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl.dll
Transaction 131489813076754311 is committing or rolling back or has already committed or rolled back
```

And I see the stack trace as
[image: Stack trace]

Everything else appears to be fine - but throwing exceptions is not great for performance.

Comment: Lets see if you get any response on the issue you created at GitHub

Comment: Yes - it's easy to reproduce as well, so hopefully we can get an answer quickly. The out of the box stateful service example shows the same behaviour - exception thrown on every commit. Not great for performance!!